# Puppet file mode => 6050 weird behaviour- doesn't apply permsion + owner group at once

Tags: hadoop, file-permissions, puppet

I need to alter permission on a existing file which was created during rpm installation. I use

```
file { '/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/bin/container-executor':
   ensure => present,
   group  => $hadoop::hadoop_group,
   owner  => 'root',
   mode   => 6050,
}
```

Quite often that is not the state founded after puppet run. I noticed that once the owner and group is changed, second time priviledges changed etc.

When I re-run the puppet apply than all is ok, permissions get changed. Nearly every time there is just one step, either changing permissions or owner+group. But to change it at once is very unusual in this case.

Does anybody has the same experience?

My OS is Linux CentOs

Thanks

Comment: Does that mode even make sense? set-uid, setgid, no permissions for owner, no permissions for other, but read+execute permissions for group? That seems very odd to me...

Comment: I didn't come up with such requirement just follow installation manual and try to automate that. http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap4-4.html